# java if statment is not working with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

can anyone let me know why the part of if statement is not working? but else work perfectly? it should be ( if there is nothing inside administrator table which is (username=varchar,, password= varchar) then let the administrator register himself.

```
if (click == buttonAdmin) {
    Connection con =myConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `adminstrator` ");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
         String username = rs.getString(1);
         String password = rs.getString(2);           

         if ( password.equals("") && username.equals("")) {
               new AdminNewRegister();                
         }
         else {
            new AdminLogin();
            System.out.println("else");
         }           
       }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

 }
```

Comment: change `rs.getString(1);` by `rs.getString("username");` the same with the password

Comment: Did you try to debug it and see what are the `password` and `username` values?

Comment: @YCF_L I think looking by index 'll work too, but the description of the table seems dodgy: (username=varchar,, password= varchar) is this a weird table, or is there one , too many?

Comment: You should definitely start using a debugger and some code formatting.

Comment: Also naming the table `adminstrator` seems weird. Maybe you meant `administrator`?

Comment: @Stultuske totally correct, but if the query is like this `select username, password from adminstrator` with with * I think It is weird what is the table contains more than username and password

Comment: @dana have you checked the values in the meantime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: SELECT * FROM `adminstrator` query will return all data from table and these all rows having some data in it,so when you are going for if condition that always fail. you just change the query to SELECT * FROM `adminstrator` where username=yourusername and password=yourpassword is that doesn't return anything that means you have to register it else you will go for login

Comment: If the table is empty, you 'll never enter the while-loop, as there will be no rows in the table...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend selecting how many administrators you have in the database using the count function and then check if it's 0 or not.

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
    if ( password.equals("") && username.equals("")) {
       new AdminNewRegister();                
    }
```

to

```
    if ( password.isEmpty() && username.isEmpty()) {
           new AdminNewRegister();                
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem. All the best:)